# overfull hbox despite of width=\linewidth

Tags: graphics, warnings

I want to include a PDF file in my LaTeX-Document, which I compile with `pdflatex`.

Using `width=\linewidth`, I still get an overfull hbox. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Warning: `Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph`

Comment: similar problem here: [(Framed) Boxes are too long / Textwidth doesn't work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106036/579)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not taking into account `\parindent` (the indentation of the first line of paragraphs not immediately after a sectional unit). Add `\noindent` before `\includegraphics`; a simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `geometry` package with its `showframe` option was only used to have a frame showing the margins for reference.