# Linewidth is Larger than the actual Linewidth

Tags: minipage

Ok I am creating a simple CV and in have the following problem. My `\linewidth` is actually larger than linewith. I tried to add `\noident` as stated on the following link

[overfull hbox despite of width=\linewidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124240/overfull-hbox-despite-of-width-linewidth)

I attach a minimal example and an image of the produced output where the problem is obvious.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\fboxrule=1pt

\noindent
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.9575\linewidth}
\begin{center}
    {\huge  \textbf{Curiculum Vitae}} \\ \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\LARGE  \textbf{My Very Long Name}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

\noindent
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
    {\huge  \textbf{Curiculum Vitae}} \\ \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\LARGE  \textbf{My Very Long Name}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few problems with your input. The main one is that you're not properly protecting end-of-lines so that they don't show as spaces in the output.

When you type

```
\fbox{
  text/box
}
```

you get the same output as if you had typed

```
\fbox{ text/box }
```

because TeX converts end-of-lines into spaces. So, if you want to use the first way, add `%` in the proper places:

```
\fbox{%
  text/box%
}
```

The second problem is that you don't take into account the `\fboxsep` space LaTeX pads the contents of an `\fbox` with.

You can avoid guessing the size by using the proper dimensions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
  \centering
  \huge\textbf{Curriculum Vitae} \\ \vspace{0.5cm}
  \LARGE\textbf{My Very Long Name}
  \end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]